# dropping SYNONYM is blocking in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, locking, blocking

I have synonyms which points to a TestDB1, by the next refresh synonyms point to TestDB2. while re-pointing from TestDB1 to TestDB2 it will drop all synonyms and re-creates them for TestDB2.

Now my problems is: while users querying from synonyms which points to TestDB1 is still running it won't let me drop synonyms. It is blocking the process synonyms re-point to TestDB2.

It only let me re-point after queries complete. Is there any other process to overcome this problem. I want to re-point synonyms while users querying?

Note: Both databases contains same tables but data will be change

Comment: From Microsoft..."Because there is no ALTER SYNONYM statement, you first have to drop the synonym...and then re-create the synonym with the same name."  This would result in a schema lock.

Answer (score 2):

No, dropping a synonym requires a Sch-M lock, and also IX locks on `sysschobjs`/`sysobjvalues`, at least if it is on the same server (I haven't tested what happens when the synonym uses a 4-part name).

What exactly would it mean if you could change a synonym in the middle of a query or transaction? If you have a query plan operator or a cursor which needs to go back to the table, or you have multiple steps in a transaction that reference the table, it would violate all kinds of principles if the referenced table were different. I think it is much better that you can't change it until a point where nobody is referencing it.

Comment: hi @Aaron Bertrand, thanks for the reply, but its live database which will use all the users, different departments use this database. Can you please suggest best option for: we have a database lets say MainDB which users will access it through synonyms but synonyms points to DB1 or DB2. normally we do update DB1 or DB2 depends on synonyms points to. means if MainDB synonyms point to DB1 then we will update DB2 then change synonyms point to DB2 vise versa. But because of this blocking issue we can't change synonyms re-point. is there alternate method for change database to MainDB?

Comment: I would treat it just like any other blocking. Start the transaction, and eventually it will take place, and the change will be reflected to any new transactions that start after that point. If you need the change to happen right this instant, your only option really is to boot all the users with `ALTER DATABASE ... SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`

Comment: If I do that, will users lost database connecton?

Comment: @user3583912 Yes. You can't pull the tablecloth out from under them without spilling a salt shaker or knocking over a glass, sorry. For the same reason you can't change a view that someone is querying and expect their transaction to switch to the new view immediately.